# Route traffic, bases on paths, between 2 VPCs using a ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

is it possible to route traffic from an ALB in VPC1 to an ALB on VPC2?

Alternatively, is possible to configure an ALB in VPC1 to have 2 listeners, and each one points to a different Target Group, one in VPC1 and the other in VPC2?

what I'm trying to do is route some traffic, bases on paths, between 2 VPCs using a ALB.

Comment: If the second LB can be Network LB, then you can. If not, then you can't do this without a custom solution.

Comment: can you elaborate @Marcin ? what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Assuming that the two vpcs are peered, having internal nlb in second vpc would give you static private ip of it. In the first vpc you would have alb with target groups based on ip addresses. So you would just use ip address of internal nlb from the second vpc

Comment: @Marcin That worked, thanks. Do you want to answer that?

Comment: Thanks. I undeleted my answer and updated it. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

If the VPC1 and VPC2 are **peered**, and VPC1 has ALB while VPC2 has NLB, joining the two load balancers between the two can be performed as followed:

1. Setup NLB in VPC2 as an **internal** balancer. This will provide a **static** private IP for the NLB.
2. Setup a target group for ALB in VPC1 that uses targets based on **IP address**. The targets can be only private IP address (not public). Therefore, you can add IP addresses of the NLB from VPC 2 as targets for ALB in VPC1.

Comment: In similar setup, if I have customer gateway in VPC2 and want to reach VPC1, should that work? Or need Transit GW instead of peering.